# Synonym for overdoing something/taking too wide an approach

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for an idiom or a synonym for a situation when someone has taken a heavy handed measure that achieves the desired effect, but also goes above this, affecting things that aren't a problem.

For example:

> If one tree is diseased, but the surrounding ones are fine, chopping down all of the trees.

I'm sure there's a phrase for this. I thought of "using a sledgehammer to crack a nut" but I'm sure there's something specific.

Answer (score 5):

[**"use a sledgehammer to crack a nut"**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/use+a+sledgehammer+to+crack+a+nut) is appropriate to use.

> to do something with more force than is necessary to achieve the result you want

---

**[overkill](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overkill)** can be used also.

> An excess of what is necessary or appropriate for a particular end

Comment: the sledgehammer doesn't really apply any disagreeable collateral damage.

Answer (score 1):

There is the old unattributed and contested pseudo-quote by reporter Peter Arnett in the Vietnam War

**"We had to destory the village in order to save it"**

Answer (score 0):

The word **blunderbuss** can be used figuratively to describe such an imprecise, indiscriminate or heavy-handed approach. Oxforddictionaries.com provides [the following definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blunderbuss) of this usage:

> An action or way of doing something regarded as lacking in subtlety and precision:
>   *economists resort too quickly to the blunderbuss of regulation*

Answer (score 0):

Try *going over the top*.

I also like **ermanen's** suggestion of *overkill* for needlessly cutting down trees, because that works both figuratively and literally.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expression [**not do things by half measures**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/half+measure).

> **half measure**: a partial, halfhearted, or weak line of actio

Comment: That doesn't fit very well. Going the extra mile is a _positive_ thing, meaning to go above and beyond the call of duty. Felling a whole area of trees because one of them is diseased is hardly positive.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a broad net.   Addresses the "taking too wide an approach" part.

Answer (score 0):

I like "Draconian" if overly harsh measures were taken.

Taking the "Nuclear Option" if you want to ruin everything to get rid of some things also works.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **The cure is worse than the desease**, i.e. the solution or proposed solution to a problem produces a worse net result than the problem does.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **The cure is worse than the desease**, i.e. the solution or proposed solution to a problem produces a worse net result than the problem does.

*This idiom may fit if the collateral dammages are too high compared to desired effect(s)*.

Answer (score -1):

One who acts **superfluously**:

[1.being more than is sufficient or required; excessive.
2.unnecessary or needless.
3.Obsolete. possessing or spending more than enough or necessary; extravagant.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/superfluous)